# Properties of a Cyclic Trapezoid

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

What are the properties of a cyclic trapezoid?

In order to prove that a quadrilateral is a cyclic trapezoid would it be sufficient to show that the diagonals are congruent?

Comment: Even if both diagonals are equal the quadrilateral might not be a trapezium - think of a kite.

Comment: how would i prove something is a cyclic trapezoid? @ParclyTaxel

Comment: right now i am working on a problem which involves proving a quadrilateral to be a cyclic trapezoid...so far i have that the diagonals are equal and also that the base angles are equal. @ParclyTaxel

Comment: "Inscribed trapezoid" is better than "Cyclic Trapezoid"

Comment: @rover2 `so far i have that ... the base angles are equal` That makes it an isosceles trapezoid, which is indeed the necessary and sufficient condition for a trapezoid to be cyclic (inscribeable).